# send username in email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

i send mail in user respective email address and when he receive mail he see info in mail like this

docname= abc
status= reject

now i want also add username and want to show who approve their documents

i save user name in session and then when any user login then his/her name visible in top right cornet  and i save this name in session

```
 Session["Login2"] = txt_username.Value;
```

now suppose supervisor login through their account and approve any documents and also send mail then when user receive mail he would be able to see mail like this

```
  docname= abc
 status=reject
 username  = john
```

email code

```
             string DocName = ((Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DocName")).Text;
                  string emailId = 
                ((Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("YourEamil")).Text;
                  DropDownList dropdownvalue = 
               ((DropDownList)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DropDownList4"));

                  string docname = String.Empty;
                  string emailID = String.Empty;
                  string dropdownvalues = String.Empty;




                  if (DocName.ToString() != "")
                  {
                      docname = DocName.ToString();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      docname = "Unavailable";
                  }
                  if (emailId.ToString() != "")
                  {
                      emailID = emailId.ToString();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      emailID = "Unavailable";
                  }

                  if (dropdownvalue.SelectedItem.ToString() != "")
                  {
                      dropdownvalues = dropdownvalue.SelectedItem.ToString();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      dropdownvalues = "Unavailable";
                  }


                  SendEmailUsingGmail(DocName, emailId, dropdownvalues);


                  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();




              }

          }
          else
          {
              Supvisor.Text = "Error";
          }
          if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
          {
              mySQLconnection.Close();
          }

                }
    private void SendEmailUsingGmail(string DocName, string emailId, string 
   dropdownvalue)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ketyycute@gmail.com", "123213");
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress("ketyycut@gmail.com");
            message.To.Add(emailId);
            //message.To.Add(New MailAddress(toEmailAddress));
            message.Subject = "Document Managment System=" + "DropDownList4" + dropdownvalue;
            message.Body = "DocName=" + DocName + " DropDownList4=" + dropdownvalue;

            smtp.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error occured: " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

how i done this

Answer (score 0):

You have the username of the person who approved it in Session.
To retrieve this:

```
string approver;
if (Session["Login2"] != null)
{
    approver = Session["Login2"].ToString();
}
```

If you also want the name of the creator/owner of the approved document in your email than you need to store it on the creation of the document.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Didn't notice the casing difference of the D char.